# velocity.js scale between 2 images

Tags: velocity.js

i'm trying to migrate my code from css to velocity for better look and feel :)
can some one please advice on what is the best way to accomplish this?
when user hovers an menu item its transforms (scale) in size, basically its a transition from one image to other

this is the pure css:

```
.site nav li a.active-page  {
background-image: url('../images/img/menu-1-hover.png');
height: 94px;
right: -8px;
width: 94px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.09s easy;
    -moz-transition: all 0.09s easy;
    -ms-transition: all 0.09s easy;
    -o-transition: all 0.09s easy;
    transition: all 0.09s easy;
}
.site #menu-2 {background-image: url('../images/img/menu-2.png');
```

}
.site #menu-2.active-page {background-image: url('../images/img/menu-2-hover.png');
}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way on the web platform to animate from one image to another. You could animate between 2 divs with different backgrounds by animating `opacity`, or you could animate `background-position`.

Nevertheless, if `scale` is what you want to animate, you could use Velocity to animate `scaleX` and `scaleY` of an element with an image.